# disable-gpu-vsync flag: initially > 300 FPS, but FPS goes back to 60 after touch a UI element or window resize

Tags: chromium-embedded, cefsharp

I am trying to run the CefSharp.WinForms.Example with no VSync on. 
In CefEamples.cs, method Init() I have added:
            `settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("disable-gpu-vsync", "disable-gpu-vsync");`

The VSync is turned off in the NVidia control panel.
I'm using http://www.vsynctester.com to test the VSync.

All goes well (FPS is roughly 300 FPS), until I touch an element of the UI (eg click on the Tear helper or resize the window), then the FPS goes back to the default 60FPS!

Question: what can i do to avoid this?

Comment: Most likely the issue is in CEF or Chromium.  I think you should try your flags with the CEF `Test App` for each different CEF branch at http://cefbuilds.com/ and see if the problem is fixed in any of them.

Comment: This issue is resolved with the latest version of CEF (3.2171.1979)